# How to reading and execute a binary file?

Tags: python

I want to read and execute binary calc.exe from reading file binary.

How to run code1 in the following script

```
file = r"calc.exe"
with open(file, "rb") as code1:
    exec(code1)
```

I don't want to direct execute calc.exe or write code1 on the files to execute

```
TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Comment: `exec` is for executing *python source code* as `str` objects or compiled `code` objects.

Comment: You don't need to read the file, Try using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Please provide more details on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

For running programs from Python, one can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) module.

Example:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(r"calc.exe")  # calc .exe needs to be availble in the working directory or from the path
outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
```

Comment: I don't want to direct execute calc.exe with subprocess or os